# How to make the command line invisible after launching the jar software using bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line

I have a bat file which launches a jar file.

```
path\to\java -jar software.jar
```

This command launches the command line in the background along with the software. I tried `start "ABCD" cmd /k path\to\java -jar software.jar` and `start "ABCD" cmd /c path\to\java -jar software.jar`and both of them didn't work.

How to make the command line invisible after the launch of the software?

Comment: I think its not directly possible using a bat file. You can think of a vbs file , something like this https://superuser.com/questions/1069972/windows-run-process-on-background-after-closing-cmd

Comment: Do not use a batch file, use a shortcut file (*.lnk) which starts with full path `javaw.exe` with the arguments required to run the Java application. No console window is opened on execution of `javaw.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

some day ago i also face this type of problem ....

but in my case i run jar file manually from CMD using

```
java -jar test.jar
```

after running this command when i close cmd jar file stop working ... so i use a trick .. to run jar file as windows service ....using this command

```
javaw -jar test.jar
```

after running this command i  close my cmd safely..

so you can try this

Comment: This is helpful but I still need the command line to be closed.

Comment: Windows command processor waits on execution of `javaw.exe` from within a batch file with processing of the batch file until the started executable (console or Windows GUI application) terminated itself. So this is no real help depending on how long the Java application in *.jar file runs. The best solution is not using a batch file with a single command line, but a shortcut file with `javaw.exe`. Otherwise `start "" "path\to\javaw.exe" -jar software.jar` can be used to start `javaw.exe` as separate process without waiting for its termination. `start /?` executed in a cmd window shows help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace java with javaw so your java application runs detached from the console window.
Then place an exit into your batch file, this may end the cmd that opened the window.